# How to get output of grep in single line in shell script?

Tags: bash, grep

Here is a script which reads words from the file replaced.txt and displays the output each word in each line, But I want to display all the outputs in a single line.

```
#!/bin/sh
 echo
 echo "Enter the word to be translated"
 read a
IFS=" "     # Set the field separator
set $a      # Breaks the string into $1, $2, ...
for a    # a for loop by default loop through $1, $2, ...
    do
    {
    b= grep "$a" replaced.txt | cut -f 2 -d" " 
    }
    done
```

Content of "replaced.txt" file is given below:

```
hllo HELLO
m AM
rshbh RISHABH
jn JAIN
hw HOW 
ws WAS 
ur YOUR
dy DAY
```

This question can't be appropriate to what I asked, I just need the help to put output of the script in a single line.

Comment: Your script is incomplete. Where is the `echo` (or `printf`) statement? The curly braces are redundant with the `do`/`done`. You only need one or the other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your entire script can be replaced by:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo
read -r -p "Enter the words to be translated: " a
echo $(printf "%s\n" $a | grep -Ff - replaced.txt | cut -f 2 -d ' ')
```

No need for a loop.

The `echo` with an unquoted argument removes embedded newlines and replaces each sequence of multiple spaces and/or tabs with one space.

Answer (score 2):

One hackish-but-simple way to remove trailing newlines from the output of a command is to wrap it in `printf %s "$(...) "`. That is, you can change this:

```
b= grep "$a" replaced.txt | cut -f 2 -d" "
```

to this:

```
printf %s "$(grep "$a" replaced.txt | cut -f 2 -d" ") "
```

and add an `echo` command after the loop completes.

The `$(...)` notation sets up a "command substitution": the command `grep "$a" replaced.txt | cut -f 2 -d" "` is run in a subshell, and its output, minus any trailing newlines, is substituted into the argument-list. So, for example, if the command outputs `DAY`, then the above is equivalent to this:

```
printf %s "DAY "
```

(The `printf %s ...` notation is equivalent to `echo -n ...` — it outputs a string without adding a trailing newline — except that its behavior is more portably consistent, and it won't misbehave if the string you want to print happens to start with `-n` or `-e` or whatnot.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS=": "; ORS=" "; } NF >= 2 { print $2; }'
```

in a pipe after the cut.